# Responsive CSS background image

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Simple concept, I'd like to have a responsive CSS background image that scales at a 1:1 width/height ratio within a browser window, this is the easy part

```
body{
    height:100%;
}

.banner{
    height:100%;
    background: url('path/to/img') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}

<body>
    <div class="banner"></div>
</body>
```

the problem is I also want to place text inside the background container with word wrapping, and have the height of the background image flow height wise with the text as a browser window resizes.

```
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eos idque epicuri...
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is this possible with pure CSS/HTML?

Comment: I"m unsure what you mean by "flow height wise with the text"... DO you want the text to scale as well?

Comment: Yeah, so I'd like the text to flow (wrap) along with the background image.  I was thinking I'd need to use media queries, but how would one determine at what resolution text begins to wrap?

Comment: Here's a good example : http://spring.io/

Comment: They are simply adjusting the font size with media queries, there isn't any calculation in CSS you could use to determine when text wraps.

Comment: Ok, so I'll probably need a few media queries along with Oriol's answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Background Image**

One way to do the background is to use `background-size: cover` as per [this post](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

---

**Text**

To do the text, you could look at using [`@media`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) queries, but as you've selected the answer, I'll leave the rest up to you guys :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
}
.banner > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.banner > .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2YCaH/)

Comment: I can iterate on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based off the answers, for anyone who is interested, to scale a CSS background image proportionately with text wrapping, the following should work in most situations.

See the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dcd018/W8ZTA/)

First to ensure the background image isn't rendered larger than mobile resolutions, I added a viewport

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .viewport {
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
}

<html>
<body>
    <div class="viewport">
        <!-- background image -->
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Then I used the `background-size:cover;` property with a height of `auto` on the background element to allow it to flow with text wrapping on mobile devices.  To allow the height of the background element to re-size relative to text wrapping, its parent (in this case, `body`), must have a height of `100%`.

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

.banner{
    background: url('path/to/banner.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .viewport {
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }

    .banner{
        height:auto;
    }

    .banner .banner-container {
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}

<html>
<body>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="banner-container">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est intellegebat definitionem at</h1>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est intellegebat definitionem at</h1>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est intellegebat definitionem at</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you  http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html .
I solved my problem like it by clearing.